# Vue.js Element Ui - trap / lock focus when el-dialog is open

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, element-ui

As you can see [here](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/dialog), when you open any dialog example and start pressing the tab key, the focus start highlighting the elements that are outside/behind the dialog. I was wondering if element-ui have something to offer which I missed to notice?

Anyhow, for now I am using [vue-focus-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-focus-lock) but I wish something native to be offered by element-ui rather pulling a library to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is answer to my own question:

First of all I tried to use `vue-focus-lock` plugin it works but also have issues when selecting the components like `el-checkbox` or `el-radio`. You can see the issue when the outside/behind content of `el-dialog` is more (below fold) then the checkbox or radio will not be checked.

Anyhow here is my solution, I have created a component `FocusLock.vue`:

```
<template lang="pug">
  div.dialog-focus-lock
    slot
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'focus-lock',

  data() {
    return {
      focusableEls: [],
      firstFocusableEl: [],
      lastFocusableEl: [],
      focusedElBeforeOpen: document.activeElement,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    handleDialogFocusLock() {
      const selectors = '' +
        'a[href], ' +
        'input:not([disabled]), ' +
        'select:not([disabled]), ' +
        'textarea:not([disabled]), ' +
        'button:not([disabled])';

      const getEls = this.$el.querySelectorAll(selectors);

      this.focusableEls = Array.prototype.slice.call(getEls);
      [this.firstFocusableEl] = this.focusableEls; // get first array item
      [this.lastFocusableEl] = this.focusableEls.slice(-1); // get last array item

      this.$el.addEventListener('keydown', e => this.handleKeyDown(e));
      this.firstFocusableEl.focus();
    },

    handleBackwardTab(e) {
      if (document.activeElement === this.firstFocusableEl) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.lastFocusableEl.focus();
      }
    },

    handleForwardTab(e) {
      if (document.activeElement === this.lastFocusableEl) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.firstFocusableEl.focus();
      }
    },

    handleKeyDown(e) {
      const KEY_TAB = 9;

      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case KEY_TAB:
          if (this.focusableEls.length === 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
          }
          if (e.shiftKey) {
            this.handleBackwardTab(e);
          } else {
            this.handleForwardTab(e);
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.handleDialogFocusLock();
  },
};
</script>
```

I wanted the component to be available globally, so imported it in `main.js` or in your case just import it wherever you need.

```
import FocusLock from '@/components/partials/FocusLock.vue';
Vue.component('FocusLock', FocusLock);
```

And using them wherever I need, just like this:

```
<template lang="pug">
  focus-lock
    el-dialog(:visible.sync="dialogVisible")
      el-form(:model="editedItem")
        // form elements goes here
</template>
```

Took some help from [HERE](https://bitsofco.de/accessible-modal-dialog/).

Also, I think you should not worry about handling `this.$el.removeEventListener`, this is taken care by vue.js, you can test by pasting below code in your browser console and run it when the `el-dialog` is open and run again when it's closed.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
  .reduce(function(pre, dom){
    var clks = getEventListeners(dom).click;
    pre += clks ? clks.length || 0 : 0;
    return pre
  }, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a bug, which element-ui hasn't fixed yet. If you want a sheer native solution, here's an idea: you can listen for a `keydown` event on a `Tab` key. In that case, you are able to access the last element (`document.activeElement`) in the dialog and prevent further tab presses. If you do that, don't forget to remove event listener when the dialog is closed. Hope this helps.

Comment: I really need a quick fix than doing something you suggested because I have almost 30 dialogs in the app I am building. And each have different kinda form elements. thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: In that case would be wise to create a directive and use it on any dialog you need.